# MongoDB updating with positional operator

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have a collection 'myCollection' of documents structured this way:

```
{
    _id: ...,
    Items: [
        {
        Field1: ..., 
        Field2:..., 
        Value: 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to update the field "Value" when I get a match on _id, Item.Field1 and Item.Field2.

Here is my query:

```
db['myCollection'].update({
        "_id" : BinData(3, "xxx"), 
        "Items.Field1" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "Items.Field2" : BinData(3, "yyy")
    }, 
     {
        $set : {
            "Items.$.Value" : NumberInt(11)
        }
    }
)
```

Sometime it works, sometime the field Value is not updated with the following response:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

The item has been found but has not been modified?...

As far as I understand "$" in this case, I think the index of the array is correct, but maybe the issue is about the "_id" criteria?

I suspect the $set expression to be wrong: Maybe I miss something to be sure the $set targets the document where {"_id" : BinData(3, "xxx")}?

Thanks a lot

**edit**
It seems that the writeResult.Modified is false because the field that needs to be modified has already been set with the value.
Actually for any Field1 and Field2 criteria, the changed item is always the same: the Items.0.Value in my case.
Could it be because of the first criteria "_id" which is not part of the array of item?

**edit**
It seems to me that the Field2 criteria is overriding the Field1 one: If I keep only one of them, it is taken into account properly.
But if I keep them both, it is as if the first one was skiped...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After further investigation I found the issue: I need to use $elemMatch operator because of the multiple criteria I have oon my array:

The query part is something like:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3, "xxx"), 
    "Items" : { 
         $elemMatch { 
             "Field1": ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
             "Field2" : BinData(3, "yyy")
     }}

}
```

Thanks for those who took time to read. Hope this can help.

**If anybody has an explanation on the reason we must use $elemMatch in this case, I am very much interested!**